# How to check if a file of given length can be created?

Tags: c, linux, file, io, size

I want to create a non-sparse file of a given length (i.e. 2GB), but I want to check if that is possible before actually writing stuff to disk.

In other words I want to avoid getting *ENOSPC* (No space left on device) while writing. I'd prefer not to create a "test file" of size 2GB or things like that just to check that there is enough space left.

Is that possible?

Comment: Windows? Linux? Microwave oven? car ABS? internet router? mobile phone? elevator controller?

Comment: Lol. Sorry. Linux. C lang

Comment: I rolled back your last edit, and just added the Linux tag, the C tag was already there.

Comment: However still you might like to add details on the storage device you are planning to use for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`statvfs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statvfs.2.html) function to determine how much free bytes (and inodes) a given filesystem has.

That should be enough for a quick check, but do remember that it's not a guarantee that you'll be able to write as much (or, for that matter, that writing more than that would have failed) - other applications could also be writing to (or deleting from) the same filesystem. So do continue to check for various write errors.

[`fallocate`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) or `posix_fallocate`  can be used to allocate (and deallocate) a large chunk. Probably a better option for your use-case. (Check the man page, there's a lot of options for space management that you might find interesting.)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`posix_fallocate(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_fallocate.3.html).

From the description:

> The function posix_fallocate() ensures that disk space is allocated
>   for the file referred to by the descriptor fd for the bytes in the
>   range starting at offset and continuing for len bytes. After a
>   successful call to posix_fallocate(), subsequent writes to bytes in
>   the specified range are guaranteed not to fail because of lack of
>   disk space